# How to store credentials using JKS

Tags: password-management

Suppose a security team specifies that credentials for an application (specifically, a database username/password) should be stored in a JKS whose password is provided to the application in a local file that is OS protected such that only the service account running the application may read it.

I have only started looking into this pattern, but I thought that JKS was used for storing certificates and the like, rather than text values.

However, it would be very convenient for the application if the credentials, and other values, could be given to the application more generally as *properties*.

Is it safe/secure to store arbitrarily named properties in the JKS (eg `database.username=foobar` and `database.password=xyz123`)?

If so, how exactly do you do it?

Comment: One Question: if it's possible to put values like this inside a JKS: how will you open it? With another password? And then what will be added? Just one Password to rule them all?

Comment: @Serverfrog One password to rule them all. However, we have side-stepped this seeming anti-pattern and intend to use (and have approved) RSA (or similar) encryption of a properties file using the public key of a key pair with the private key injected into the app container.

Comment: so in short, you just want to obscure the values. it just one step more to read them in cleartext and it isn't even a hard one ;)

Comment: (necroed?) The `java.security.KeyStore` API supports 'SecretKeyEntry' which can actually contain any bytes, but the JKS _format_ does not implement it. You could instead use JCEKS format which does, but was restricted in early versions of Java (through 6 I think) and thus most people aren't familiar with and many apps don't support; or PKCS12 format which (as used in Java at least 8 up) supports this, though without the interoperability with non-Java things that 'normal' (privatekey+certificate) PKCS12 has.